# TabControl (SelectedTab) does not work, how can I fix this?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, tabcontrol

I am working on a Project in the Moment and have a Problem with the selection of a Tab in TabControll. I tried to select a Tab with TabControl.SelectedTab, but then an error appears that says, that SelectedTab does not exists. Is there anything I am missing? Down below is the Code how I tried to select a Tab.

```
TabControl tabControl1 = new TabControl();
tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabControl1.TabPages["tb_config"];
```

Thx for any help :)

Comment: Please add a tag specifying the UI framework you use (WPF, WinForms, Xamarin, UWP, ASP.NET, Unity, ...)

Comment: Are you talking about a compilation error or runtime exception? What TabControl are you talking about? Windows Forms controls aren't the same as WPF controls or ASP.NET Core components. If you try to use a component that *doesn't* have a `SelectedTab` property you'll get a compilation error saying exactly that

Comment: WinForms TabControl [*does* have that property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selectedtab?view=windowsdesktop-6.0). You can't get that error when using the WinForms TabControl. Post code that actually reproduces the problem and the *full* exception or error

Comment: It says that TabControl does not contain a definition for Selected Tab

Comment: Right-click the word "TabControl" and select Go To Definition.  Some odds that you'll now find your own TabControl class.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, maybe you should [create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finally got the solution:

```
System.Windows.Forms.TabControl tabControl1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TabControl();
                         
this.tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 2;
```

If I use this Code, it works without Problems :)